# How to deploy GitHubPages when it is connected to mongodb atlas?

Tags: node.js, github, github-actions, github-pages

I have created sample angular application to test GitHubPages deployment..
[image]

Backend has a node js code which is connected to MongoDB Atlas.

Frontend has angular which is working fine when starting backend and frontend both.

When I build project, it has fully angular component only.. So I moved to backend into frontend folder and which is now

[image]

still when I build and I need to copy paste the database component and dist in one single folder.

If I do that npm install and node index.js it is working fine..

[image]

The same i am trying to do in GitHubPages using Actions. until dist folder is fine.. How to move database backend files in to ghPages to up the service. without db files i except html page but showing 404. How to copy db files from master to ghpages branch.

My repository is given https://github.com/changan1111/UserManagement

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Github pages can only serve static files (HTML,CSS, js, images, etc.)
It might serve your bundled Angular application, but your API calls will need to be done to a hosted backend.

You can check Google Cloud, AWS, Heroku, Azure for hosting the backend.
Be sure to set CORS properly.